# Django: Update Model-Field everytime a Foreign-Key is associated with said model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

Lets suppose we have the following classes:

```py
class Cart(models.Model):
      total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
```

and

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
      cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'd like to **update the total everytime a Cart-Item is added to the Cart**. When/ How can I call my *addItUp()* method here?

Thought about using a signal like this, but this doesn't trigger:

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=CartItem, weak=False)
def post_save_cartItem_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    print("inside signal")
```

> Here's my very simplified *addToCart()* method:

```
    def add(self, request, product_id, cart_obj):
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
        CartItem.objects.create(cart=cart_obj, ...)
        cart_obj.save()
        return True
```

This is my first question here, if i can better my explanation please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

A common problem that people have when creating triggers is that they forget (or don't know) to import signals in their `apps.py` file.  That's the only reason that I can imagine your signal wouldn't be triggering.

I imagine your `apps.py` file should look something like (if the name of your app is `Shop`):

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ShopConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'Shop'

    def ready(self):
        import Shop.signals
```

You can then use the `post_save` signal for a CartItem to get its related Cart, add up the total value, and save the Cart with a new total.

Comment: woohoo! that's the one thing that people tend to miss when working with signals. Signals are SUPER useful, so have fun